# Could $\pi$, raised to some power can give rational result?

Tags: pi

For example $\sqrt 7$ is irrational but $\sqrt 7$ raised to power $2$ is rational. Similarly, is it possible that $\pi$ raised to some power (say $n$) could be rational ?

Comment: No, pi is transcendental.

Comment: $\pi^0 = 1$ is rational XD

Comment: so you mean integer prower right? otherwise the answer would be an immediate yes.

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören is asking for the right clarification.  Otherwise,$\pi^{\ln2 /\ln \pi} =2$.

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören The transcendentality argument also applies to positive rational powers.

Comment: @ArnaudD. yes, I mean just a bit more information would be good. The OP gave $2$ as an example so my most likely guess would be that he meant first of all integers.

Answer (score 3):

For any positive rational value $q$, we have

$$\pi^{\log_{\pi}(q)} = q$$

so certainly yes, $\pi$ to some power can be rational.

---

If, however, you only allow integer powers, then the answer is no. In fact, even if you would allow *rational* nonzero powers of $\pi$, the answer is no. We know this because we know that $\pi$ is a transcendental number*, which means it is not the root of any polynomial with rational coefficients. If there would exist some rational number $r=\frac{a}{b}$ (where $a,b\in\mathbb N$) such that $\pi^r = q\in\mathbb Q$, then we would have

$$0=\left(\pi^r\right)^b-(q^a)^b = \pi^a - q^{ab}$$

which means that $\pi$ would be the solution to the equation $x^a-q^{ab}=0$, which we know is impossible.

---

* Proving $\pi$ is transcendental was quite a feat back when it was first done and was by no means an easy task!

Comment: Could an algebraic exponent do ?

Comment: @Arthur I changed the wording.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Interesting question! Don't know the answer from the top of my head though...

Comment: @5xum I'd venture to say no. But, algebraic numbers can be pretty weird.

Comment: Here I meant that, is there any power (any complex number) upto which π is raised to get rational number?

Comment: @MR.HACKERBUDDY Did you read the first three lines of my answer, by any chance?

Comment: I meant what is that power ? How can we calculate it ?

Comment: @MR.HACKERBUDDY The first three lines of my answer tell you that $\pi$ to some power is equal to $q$, where $q$ is any positive ratonal number. I don't know how much more obvious I can make it.

Comment: I want to say is there any identity of π just as for e {e^(πi)=-1}.